# Spring log setting not used in production

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am Java newbie and have to maintain a spring boot project. I changed the log settings from logback to log4j2 because I would like to use the JsonLayout to analyze the logs with ElasticSearch.

It works locally but in production I only get the default settings, e.g. like

```
018-04-24 07:50:19.969 INFO 5 --- [pool-3-thread-1] c.e.r.s.SessionService : Session backup completed: 0 failed, 0 succeeded!
```

My build script is a Dockerfile, where I just use `RUN mvn package` to create the package.

Application.properties

```
#
# Spring Webservice Configuration 
#
server.port:9002
management.port:9001

#
# Profile
#
spring.profiles.active:production

#
# Rule Server Configuration
#
ruleServer.uniqueName:localhost

#
# REST endpoints
#
easierlife.events.endpoint:/api/households/%s/events?auth_token=%s
easierlife.session.endpoint:/api/sessions

orbit.clusterMode:local
orbit.clusterName:easierlife-rs
orbit.nodeName:host

#
# Database configuration
#
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

# Spring JPA config:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy:org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.show-sql:false
```

Log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <JsonLayout eventEol="true" compact="true" stacktraceAsString="true" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The basic project structure is:

```
- src
  - main
    - java
      - resources
        = application.properties
        = log4j2.xml
 = pom.xml
```

Comment: can you add the `application.properties` file ?

Comment: Sure, I have added it

Comment: i can't find the log4j configuration, can you add it please

Comment: There is no configuration. According to the docs, log4j is used automatically if the package is added. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html. Spring Boot supports Log4j 2 for logging configuration if it is on the classpath. If you use the starters for assembling dependencies, you have to exclude Logback and then include log4j 2 instead.

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the log4j config inside application.properties.

Comment: The issue looks like that when running locally, the application gets the "log4j2.xml" and uses that to configure logging. But in production, it mostly likely does not "see" the log4j2.xml and proceeds with default configuration. Can you let us know how the project structure is and where the log4j2.xml is kept.

Comment: Sure, I added these information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not realized that my file was named Log4j2.xml and not log4j2.xml (uppercase L). I was not aware that the virtual file system of the classpath is case sensitive under Linux.